# Interactive ZSH's command prompt to execute a ZLE command

Tags: terminal, shell, zsh, prompt, interactive

Is there any way to interactively run a **ZLE** command on the current line?

I am looking for a similar way to **TMUX**'s `command-prompt`, which default keybinding is `prefix :` were you can run a **TMUX** command on the current session.

Use case: run a **ZLE** command that doesn't have any keybinding on the current line.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is, and it's called [`execute-named-cmd`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Miscellaneous). By default, it's bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> in Zsh's "emacs" keymap and to <kbd>:</kbd> in the "vicmd" keymap (to which you can switch by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> in the "viins" keymap).